# Theorem 5.8 from baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis

*Let $f$ be defined on $[a,b]$; if $f$ has  a local maximum at a point $x\in(a,b)$ and if $f'(x)$ exists, then $f'(x)=0$.*

I think that the converse of this theorem is not true. Taking $f(x)=x^3$ on $[-1,1]$. and $f'(0)=0$ but $0$ is not local maximum.

Am I right?

Comment: I think you know you are.

Comment: @JohnDouma, Thank you!